# Script only runs partially when run as cron

Tags: cron

I wrote a script that uses a program to create a CSV from an iCOBOL flat file. Unfortunately, the program just adds on to the end of the file and doesn't overwrite it. So I added a line to the script to first remove the file. Everything works well when I run it manually. When I have cron run it, it seems to just delete the file and then stop. Did I miss something? Please see my code below.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/directory
rm -f file.csv
icreorg -O l flatfile file.csv
```

The icreorg is the program that is generating the csv.

Thank you!

Comment: Probably need the full path to icreorg.

Comment: Worked! Why is that necessary?

Comment: `cron jobs` don't load the user environment, `$PATH` variable include. So you need full path to executables or explicitly load your .profiles from your script.

Comment: My linux lesson for the day. Thanks for the help!